# MVC - helpers and Joomla

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla

I'm being confused, I have a function that needs to update some table, I have placed it inside controller, however now I have found that I will need to use it inside other 2 controllers.

What is the best practice to place the function that making updates and where to place it and how to call it?

maybe helper?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your models by extending `JTable`? In this case, just add the method there. It's perfectly ok to have business logic in the model such as "increment all rows of this user id by one" (static method) or "split up this name and save it into columns first name & second name" (normal method).

Comment: Ok so for eg. I have placed this function inside a model how to call it inside different model than? the idea is to not copy same functions for each model

Answer (score 0):

The helper would need to be relevant to the controller, as it will be applied to all controllers. I will assume that not all controllers would see meaning in calling the Update.

You could create a static class with a static method that would update your table.

etc Add a file to the Models folder and then create the following class.

```
public static CalledFromMultipleLocations
{
     public static void UpdateMyTable(string somedata)
     {
          //Do you update code.
     }
}
```

Without knowing your business object model its hard to really provide a solution.